# How to compile FastCGI++ Code?

Tags: gcc, g++, fastcgi, fastcgi++

What command should I use to compile FastCGI++ Code?

The documented command gives me several errors.

```
user@user:~/code$ g++ -o main.fcgi main.cpp pkg-config –libs –cflags fastcgi++
g++: error: pkg-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: –libs: No such file or directory
g++: error: –cflags: No such file or directory
g++: error: fastcgi++: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could one of the missing libraries be `Fastcgipp`, perchance?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have linked `fcgi++` as documented on the documentation: http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/doc/2.1/

Comment: Apparently not... You've got multiple errors that say it can't find the necessary functions.  Wrong version?  Missing header file?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added Source Code and Included Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes FastCGI++ is compiled with it's Boost libraries dynamically. This means, afaik, that you need to link to them as well when you compile your code.

```
g++ -o main.fcgi main.cpp -lfastcgipp -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

Answer (score 0):

You need backticks for you pkg-config command

```
g++ -o main.fcgi main.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags fastcgi++`
```

In my system, this command is interpreted as

```
g++ -o main.fcgi main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lfastcgipp -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_date_time-mt
```